# Is the number of template parameters for std::vector guaranteed to be 2?

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer

I currently have a body of code that relies on `std::vector<...>` having exactly two template arguments.  Which as of this writing, all language revisions do. If this number changes, my code will break.

Is it possible that in some future revision, this number will be changed, or does the standard guarantee that this number will always be 2?

Comment: if your code breaks, then it is a breaking change, no?

Comment: There's no requirement today that any implementation provide an implementation of `std::vector` that only has two template arguments.   Implementations are free to add additional template arguments with defaulted values.

Comment: @MarshallClow are you sure? That would make it impossible to use `std::vector` as template template parameter in a portable way

Comment: @MarshallClow even if it is not specified, there is lots of code that relies on `std::vector` having 2 arguments, to it would be breaking change in any case.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Not impossible at all since P0522.

Comment: perhaps rephrase the question a little: "Is `std::vector` required to have 2 template arguments?". Because if your code breaks then it breaks, but what matters is whether your code relies on something guaranteed by the standard, or whether it relies on implementation details (in which case your code breaking would be your fault)

Comment: The only "breaking" consequence I see is that your objects may fail to link against a newer standard library shared object (since mangling may be affected). But that's a good thing really. If you rebuild your code against your standard library often (if you have decent CI/CD), I don't a potential for problems.

Comment: I realise now that I have worded this question poorly.  I guess what I am actually trying to ask is if I can relatively safely make assumptions about the number of template arguments, i.e. this is not a change the standards body will make likely.  Since as @463035818_is_not_a_number pointed out if it breaks, by definition it's a breaking change.  Not sure how to fix the question without closing and opening a new one.  Also the breaking code does involve template template parameters as pointed out.

Comment: @MarshallClow I'm not sure that's true. The standard does state this about member functions: "**[member.functions]/2** For a non-virtual member function described in the C++ standard library, an implementation may declare a different set of member function signatures, provided that any call to the member function that would select an overload from the set of declarations described in this International Standard behaves as if that overload were selected." But it doesn't specifically say anything similar about class templates. It doesn't look like extra template parameters are in fact allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find such guarantees, but for what it's worth, I also think it would be exceedingly unlikely, because the standards committee is in general very concerned with anything that might break existing code. The allocator-aware design of std::vector and several other templates has been present since C++98. Additionally, you could say it is complete: it knows the type of its elements, and of the allocator that will handle (de)allocation of memory for those elements. What other template parameters could it need?